# How to display a table of images in R output in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

How do I take a list of image URLs, and display them in an HTML table in a Jupyter notebook with an R kernel?

Here's a list of URLs:

```
image_urls = c('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdQNM.jpg',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oysP.jpg')
```

Here's some code to display one image from an `image_url`:

```
library(jpeg)
library(RCurl)

img <- RCurl::getBinaryURL(image_url)
jj <- jpeg::readJPEG(img,native=TRUE)
plot(0:1,0:1,type="n",ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
rasterImage(jj,0,0,1,1)
```

**Edit**: Another way to think of this is, is there functionality like ipython's `display`?  It looks like there might be in https://github.com/IRkernel/repr.  I have to read more.

Comment: would a simple `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` do what you want?

Comment: Do you really need this on the R output? You could easily use`![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdQNM.jpg)` on a markdown pane.

Comment: @Marcelo I want to programmatically generate the URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m the maintainer of all IRkernel-related projects.

[`IRdisplay`](https://irkernel.github.io/docs/IRdisplay/0.4.4/reference.html) is the package you’re searching for, specifically [`display_jpeg`](https://irkernel.github.io/docs/IRdisplay/0.4.4/display_-less-than-image-greater-than.html):

```
library(IRdisplay)
display_jpeg(file = 'filename.jpg')
```

Sadly the `file` parameter doesn’t work with URLs (yet), so you have to  manually pass data to it:

```
jpeg_data <- RCurl::getBinaryURL(image_url)
display_jpeg(jpeg_data)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I actually will end up using display_html() so I can lay out multiple images, but I'll accept this answer.